# Как избавиться от округления шага в NumberAxis?

Tags: java, javafx

Если установить у NumberAxis поле tickUnit в целое число, то у шага сетки на графике происходит округление (суть видна на первой пикче), ну а если tickUnit задавать вещественным, то округление пропадает (видно на второй пикче). Как сделать так, чтобы и в случае целых чисел не было этого округления?

[image: целочисленный tickUnit]

[image: вещественный tickUnit]

Answer (score 1):

Задать не целое число, а вещественное: `tickUnit = 20.0`

Comment: Пробовал уже, не помогает это - округляется всё также